# How to prevent a local state reset while dispatching action to reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I am building a simple database and I am implementing Search Criteria form. I want to dispatch an action to Reducer **only when the form is submitted**.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return {
    onSubmittedForm: (criteria) => dispatch(compActions.submitCriteria(criteria))
};
```

};

`criteria` is an object stored is a local state:

```
state = {
    criteria: {
        group: '',
        province: '',
        realms: []
    }
}
```

and in the same manner (currently) in Reducer.

When I dispatch action to Reducer then **the local state gets reset**. I can see the criteria correctly in Reducer, they are mapped then correctly to *props*. The local state is also working fine.

To initialise Criteria component I use:

```
<Criteria
     options={this.props.options}
     realms={this.state.criteria.realms}
     realmsChanged={this.handleCriteriaRealmsChange}
     formSubmitted={this.handleCriteriaFormSubmission}
 />
```

`realms` is one of the criteria.

I am forced to use *the local state*, otherwise, I have to dispatch action to Reducer whenever input changes (to be able to obtain the updated value from `this.props.criteria.realms` instead of `this.state.criteria.realms`, as it is now) which works fine too, but the essential requirement is to update Reducer' state only upon form submission, not on input change.

To reflect the issue, it would be tempting to use as a value something like:

```
const realms = (this.props.criteria.realms && this.props.criteria.realms.length > 0) ? this.props.criteria.realms : this.state.criteria.realms;
```

but I know it isn't the right approach.

Perhaps there is a way to keep the state untouched after the action is dispatched to Reducer? Could you please advise?

---

**UPDATE**

I simplified the component. Currently, on every change, the component (and all other components that rely on `<Criteria />`) re-render because onChange dispatches new `group` value to Reducer (which is then mapped to `this.props.criteria.group`). This works but I want to perform re-render for all the components only when I submit the form via a button click.

Currently, the `onCriteriaFormSubmission` does nothing because the state is already updated due to onChange.

That's why I thought the idea of the local state will work but it doesn't because `group` field expects value that must be `this.props.criteria.groups` if I pass this already to Reducer, otherwise it's always empty...

So the only thing that comes to my mind is to not pass the criteria values to Reducer upon a single criteria field change (in this case `groups` but can be more of them) but somehow submit them all together upon form submission via: `onCriteriaFormSubmission`). However, I am ending up in an infinite loop because then I have no way to display the true value when a criteria field changes.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from '../../UI/Inputs/Select/Select';
import { Button, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import * as companiesActions from '../../../store/actions/companies';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
class Criteria extends Component {

render = () => {
    return (
        <section>
            <Form onSubmit={this.props.onCriteriaFormSubmission}>
                <Form.Field>
                    <Select
                        name='group'
                        options={this.props.options.groups}
                        placeholder="Choose group"
                        multiple={false}
                        value={this.props.criteria.group}
                        changed={this.props.onGroupChange}
                    />
                </Form.Field>
                <Button
                    type='submit'
                    primary>
                    Search
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </section>
    );
}

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    criteria: state.r_co.criteria,
    options: {
        groups: state.r_op.groups
    }
};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return {
    onCriteriaFormSubmission: (criteria) => dispatch(companiesActions.criteriaFormSubmission(criteria)),
    onGroupChange: (event, data) => dispatch(companiesActions.groupChange(event, data))
};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Criteria);
```

---

**UPDATE 2 with RESOLUTION:**

I tried the preventDefault() method of event upon submit, suggested in the comments but it didn't help either. I started to think the problem may be somewhere else, outside the component as the state clearly got reset upon dispatch (submitting form did not cause reset).

I started to learn about React Router and Store persistence and decided to double check the Redux implementation.

My index.js was like this:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>
```

while inside App.js my `<BrowserRouter>` was wrapped around `<Aux>` component. Once I moved `<BrowserRouter>` directly under `<Provider>` the reset problem disappeared and everything behaves as it should now.

So my index.js is now

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I've never had to retain local state after form submission, this behavior seems pretty strange. Could you maybe use preventDefault on the method that handles the form to prevent the page from reloading after submission?

Let me know if that works.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help. The same behavior happens when I simply execute button onClick. What is the best approach to pass my local state to the Reducer? Is it ok to do this via `dispatch`, passing it (or its part) as a parameter?

Comment: I think it is fine to pass local state to reducer via dispatch. I typically create an empty object, add the parts of the local state I want to it, then send the object to the reducer as a parameter of dispatch.

Comment: Can you show the component code where the local state resets? Let me see if I can recreate the problem(and possibly, a solution)

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like you have prevented the default behavior of form reload(given that you put the submit handler on a form rather than a button.  This is what you should try: create a submit method before your render method. This method should take a parameter 'event' which will then call the prevent default method before calling the methods to send form data to store.

```
criteriaSubmisssion = event => { event.preventDefault(); this.props.onCriteriaFormSubmission() }
```

Your form OnSubmit method should call criteriaSubmission instead.

Comment: It is true, and it probably stops the form from reset, you're right, but all the values are already in the Reducer's state and I prefer to submit them upon click, not upon change. I am trying to figure out the right design pattern here.

Comment: The method I put there is for the form's onSubmit event, not for the input  element's onChange event. You're still submitting them on click.